# App does not start in Emulator

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create an app with Xamarin.Android. The app does not start in the android emulator.

Comment: have you installed the app in the emulator?

Comment: Are you just trying to run the sample? Does the Emulator even start? Please provide full reproduction steps and error messages.

Comment: On Windows? It is pretty slow to launch the emulator and deploy the app. Please follow Xamarin's guide and be patient. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello%2C_world If you cannot get it working, make sure you have properly installed it, http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation

Comment: To chrkad what are the specific steps for installing.

The steps I did were:
1. Debug application
2.From the list of emulators, I pick one and click start emulator.
3. I want for andoir to start up and then when i browse the app, I cant find my new app

Comment: The buildoutput I have uploaded at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LOPPsCZjtdm5DVzoPOT5E2QlfQ2txyL8nC-imVM7rqc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am sure this is a pretty straightword issue to anyone who has considerable experience in Xamarin.

Comment: Cheesebaron, chrkad, lex li anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...and the strange thing was that i had the same issue in every week or two.
**My Solution was changing the Minimum Android Version, to lower or higher.**